# With jQuery slideDown/slideUp on hover, how to wait until previous slide finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down menu where the drop-down slides open, then slides back closed.

```
$('nav ul li').hover(
     function () {
        $(this).children('.subnav').slideDown(300);
    }, 
     function () {
        $(this).children('.subnav').slideUp(300);
    }
);
```

If someone hovers over one item, then another before the previous finishes sliding up, they overlap. How do I prevent this overlap and make the previous slide up before allowing the second to slide down?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slide-on-hover-queue-build-up) can help you.
I also started trying with a boolean variable to check when the next animation is allowed, but I didn't have much success. So the last answer in the thread I mentioned may be your answer too.
Good luck!